# How to create a remote link or form that performs a synchronous ajax request

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am familiar with the `remote: true` option that you can give to forms and links. However AJAX request that are made through these forms and links are always asynchronous.

I know that you can make synchronous AJAX requests with jQuery, and I wonder how one would achieve this using `remote: true`.

I think it is possible, since it was possible before using link_to_remote http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/PrototypeHelper/link_to_remote. But I can't find any documentation on it.